# Mongoose $push keeps adding two entries

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Here are my `user` and `product` schemas:

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
  //... 
  addedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users"
  }
});

const userSchema = new Schema({   
  //...
  addedItems: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: "products"
  }]
});

mongoose.model("products", productSchema);
mongoose.model("users", userSchema);
```

In my Node back end route I do this query:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: req.body.id },
  { $push: { addedItems: newProduct._id } },
  { upsert: true, new: true },
  function(err, doc) {
    console.log(err, doc);
  }
);
```

The `console.log` prints out this:

```
{
    //...
    addedItems: [ 5ab0223118599214f4dd7803 ]
}
```

Everything looks good. I go to actually look at the data using the front-end website for my mongo db; I'm using [mlab.com](https://mlab.com), and this is what shows:

```
{
//...
"addedItems": [
        {
            "$oid": "5ab0223118599214f4dd7803"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "5ab0223118599214f4dd7803"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Question:** What the heck happened? Why does it add an additional entry into addedItems ?! Even though my console.log only showed one.

**Note:**

I tested to see if the backend route was being called more than once. It is not.

It seems to be a problem with `$push` because if I just have `{ addedItems: newProduct._id }` then only one entry goes in, but it overwrites the entire array.

**Edit:**

Made a test project to produce the same results: https://github.com/philliprognerud/test-mcve-stackoverflow

Can anyone figure out what's going on?

Comment: Maybe you end up calling it twice?

Comment: @Johnny I'm pretty sure I'm not calling 'findOneAndUpdate' twice. There's not a lot of code I'm dealing with either. So i'm wondering how this could be happening. Also since I'm doing 'new: true' it should be returning the most up to date doc. And it only shows one.

Comment: The only thing I'm doing after that update is calling res.send(...) and it goes back to my React front end. Keep in mind this is only happening with '$push', if I try to just do '{ addedItems: newProduct._id }' then only one entry goes in. But it overwrites everything obviously.

Comment: @JohnnyHK https://github.com/philliprognerud/test-mcve-stackoverflow

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is caused by your mixed used of promises (via async/await) and callbacks with the `findOneAndUpdate` call which ends up executing the command twice.

To fix the problem:

```
const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { id: userID },
  { $push: { addedItems: newProduct.id } },
  { upsert: true, new: true }
);

console.log(updatedUser);
```

Future readers note that the use of `await` isn't shown here in the question, but is in the MCVE.

Comment: Thank you! Solution works, and reasoning makes sense.

Comment: Can you please explain why it happens? Why does the operation get executed twice if you pass a callback function?

Comment: @lucifer63 I assume it's because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53970919/1259510).

Answer (score 2):

I am facing similar issue. Just landed to this page. I find that previous answer is not very descriptive. So posting this:

```
export const updateUserHandler = async (req, res) => {
    const request = req.body;    
 await  User.findOneAndUpdate(                  //<== remove await 
  { _id: request.id },
  { $push: { addedItems: newProduct._id } },
  { upsert: true, new: true },
  (findErr, findRes) => {
        if (findErr) {
          res.status(500).send({
            message: 'Failed: to update user',
            IsSuccess: false,
            result: findErr
          });
        } else {
          res.status(200).send({
            message: 'Success:  to update user',
            IsSuccess: true,
            result: findRes
          });

        }
      }
);
  }
```

Here there are two async calls one is the **async** and other is **await**. Because of this there are two entries in the document. Just remove await from  **await**  User.findOneAndUpdate. It will work perfectly.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

When you await Query you are using the promise-like, specifically, `.then()` and `.catch(()` of Query. Passing a callback as well will result in the behavior you're describing.

If you await Query and `.then()` of Query simultaneously, would make the query execute twice

use:

```
await Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, doc, options)
```

OR

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, doc, options, callback)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code $push keeps adding two entries:
    const ali={ "_id": "5eaa39a18e7719140e3f4430" };

```
//   return await customerModel.findOneAndUpdate(
//     ali,
//     {
//       "$push": {
//         "address": [objAdr],
//       },
//     },
//     function (error: any, success: any) {
//       if (error) {
//         console.log(error);
//       } else {
//         console.log(success);
//       }
//     }
//   );
```

My solutions working true:

```
return await customerModel
.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: ids },
  { $push: { "address": objAdr } }
)
.catch((err: string | undefined) => new Error(err));
```