# Mongoose promises documentation says queries are not promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

From the docs (**Mongoose v5.4.1**, latest version):

> Mongoose async operations, like .save() and queries, return
>   thenables. 
>       This means that you can do things like MyModel.findOne({}).then()

second parapraph from the docs states:

> Mongoose queries are not promises. They have a .then() function for co
>   and async/await as a convenience.

What **Javascript MDN** webpage states:

> The then() method returns a Promise.

Does this mean that mongoose has another kind of implementation for async functions where they reserved the then keyword for the result of the async action?

In other words, they act like promises but are not JS promises?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises):

> Mongoose queries are not promises. They have a `.then()` function for co
>   and async/await as a convenience. However, unlike promises, calling a
>   query's `.then()` can execute the query multiple times.

So unlike an actual promise, if you call `then()` multiple times on the query, you actually execute the query (or update) multiple times.

If you want an actual promise, call [`exec()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) on the query.

```
let promise = Test.findOne({}).exec();
```

Answer (score 10):

All *promises* are *thenables*, but not all *thenables* are *promises*. To make things more complicated, not all *promises* are `Promise`s (instances created by JavaScript's built-in `Promise` constructor).

JavaScript promises are an implementation of the [Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/), which defines the terms like this:

> 1.1 “promise” is an object or function with a `then` method whose behavior conforms to this specification.
>
> 1.2 “thenable” is an object or function that defines a `then` method.

So Mongoose's queries are **not** promises, not even by that definition, since their `then` method **is not** compatible with the Promises/A+ spec. See [JohnnyHK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53970919/157247) for why they aren't compatible with the Promises/A+ spec (they run the query).

> In other words, they act like promises but are not JS promises?

They only act a bit like promises. They **are not** promises. Their `then` is not implemented per the spec, it has side effects (running the query). If you want a true promise, see [JohnnyHK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53970919/157247) (e.g., use `exec`).

---

In general, if you have a *thenable* that's at least somewhat promise-like, you can get a proper promise for it by using `Promise.resolve`:

```
Promise.resolve(theThenable)
.then(/*...*/)
.catch(/*...*/)
.finally(/*...*/);
```

`Promise.resolve` will provide a true `Promise` instance that is *resolved to* the Mongoose thenable/promise: It will wait for that thenable/promise to settle and then settle the same way. That would work on a Mongoose query (provided you only do it once; `exec` is the better way with Mongoose queries).

Comment: I get it. In other words, the catch() after the then() will be meaningless if I don't pack it in an Promise?

Comment: @eugen If it is a "promise", the `.then()` has to return a "promise", you can just use it as a `Promise`, there won't be any differences.

Comment: @eugensunic - All the Mongoose documentation promises to provide is `then` (which, if it's per-spec, can be used for `catch` situations as well). But if you want to actually use `catch` or `finally` on the object, get a true `Promise` instead (via `Promise.resolve(theThenable)`. If all you need is the `then` method, then you can use it directly.

Comment: @JonasWilms - It depends. If Mongoose's `then` returns a Mongoose promise that isn't a `Promise`, and Eugen passes that to something expecting a true `Promise`, it could be problematic. All of the ways promises are consumed in the JavaScript spec only rely on `then`, but that doesn't apply to userland code...

Comment: @eugensunic - FWIW, I think [JohnnyHK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53970919/157247) is a better Mongoose-specific answer than the above, which is more general.

Answer (score 4):

They are "promise like", which means you can `await` them and call `.then()` and `.catch()` on them, however they are not `instanceof Promise`.