# Mongoose regarding the use of then()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wanted to delete a document from my collection. 
Then, I have the following code. Here, the variable `classmates` refers to my collection in mongoDB. 
Then I tried to run the following in the terminal by typing `node myFile.js`. 
Then, no any document was deleted.

```
classmates.findOneAndDelete({
  classmate: "Mary";
})
```

I then tried to add `then()` (as follows). After running that in the terminal,
I successfully deleted one document. 
Why did my first code fail to do so? What is the reason behind?
I tried to think of whether it is because of async function, but it seems not relevant...
Sincerely thank you for your help in advance!

```
classmates.findOneAndDelete({
  classmate: "Mary"
}).then(() => {
      //nothing to do here 
})
```

Comment: please use deleteOne({condition}) methode

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53970919/11717458

Comment: It seems without using then, it simply does not execute.