# MongoClient's findOne() never resolves on Electron, even when collection is populated

Tags: javascript, mongodb, electron

I'm working on making a web app with Electron and I successfully connected to a Mongo DB Atlas database and I'm able to send information to it. However, I seem to be unable to retrieve it. The first snippet of code that I included is how I connected to the database.

```
MongoClient.connect(URI, (err, client) => {
    
    if (err){
        console.log("Something unexpected happened connecting to MongoDB Atlas..."); 
    }

    console.log("Connected to MongoDB Atlas..."); 

    currentDatabase = client.db('JukeBox-Jam-DB'); /* currentDatabase contains a Db */ 
});
```

Then, this second snippet is how I've been writing to the database, which seems to work perfectly fine.

```
ipc.on('addUserToDatabase', (event, currentUser) => {
   
    const myOptions = {
        type: 'info', 
        buttons: ['Continue'], 
        defaultId: 0, 
        title: 'Success', 
        message: 'Your account has been created.'
    };

    dialog.showMessageBox(mainWindow, myOptions);

    currentCollection = currentDatabase.collection('UsersInformation');
    currentCollection.insertOne(currentUser);

});
```

Lastly, this is the code that I've been trying to use to retrieve information from the database. I don't see where I could be making a mistake so that it is not working for retrieving, but yes for writing. From my understanding findOne() when passed without parameters should simply return a Promise that resolves to the first entry that matches the query that is passed to it. If a query is not provided then it will resolve to the item that was put in the database first. If there's no entry that matches the query, then it should resolve to null. Any ideas why this isn't working?

```
ipc.on('checkUsernameRegistration', (event) => {

    currentCollection = currentDatabase.collection('UsersInformation'); 
    
    let myDocument = currentCollection.findOne(); /* I don't understand why this isn't working! */ 

    console.log(myDocument); /* This prints Promise { <pending> } */ 

    if (myDocument !== null){ /* If myDocument is not null, that means that that there is already someone with that username in the DB. */ 


    }

});
```

Thanks to everyone that is attempting to help me! I've been stuck in this for several hours now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose promises documentation says queries are not promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53970784/mongoose-promises-documentation-says-queries-are-not-promises)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `async/await` :

```
ipc.on('checkUsernameRegistration', async (event) => {
    currentCollection = currentDatabase.collection('UsersInformation'); 
  
    let myDocument = await currentCollection.findOne({ _id: value });  

    if (myDocument !== null){ 
       console.log(myDocument);
    }
});
```

or, you need to pass a  `callback`, like this:

```js
currentCollection.findOne({ country: 'Croatia' }, function (err, doc) {
  if (err) console.error(err);
  console.log(doc);
});
```

This happens because [queries are not promises](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html). Actually, I recommend you to study the difference between `async` and `sync` code in node.js. Just to understand where the callback should be passed to function, and where you can simply write `await Model.method({ options })`.

Comment: Awesome, did this work and solved the issue. I will read over the link that you referenced as it seems quite interesting. I'm not that familiar with synchronous and asynchronous programming so hopefully I will learn a thing or two.

Comment: @MysteriousEnigma, if my answer was helpful, then please accept it as an answer, so it will close question as solved or upvote it. (Or you could do both, by your desire)