# Mongoose deleteOne() and deleteMany() not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I was working on a learning project creating a simple web application to write and store todos when I faced a problem that I wasn't able to **delete entries in my MongoDB database**. I created this simple JavaScript app with mongoose module to recreate the problem. It creates `item1` object with the name `"test"` and stores it in a database. Then it deletes all the objects with the `"test"` name. As you can see on the screenshot the app creates and stores successfully objects but **ignores deleting them, which is my initial goal**.

I thank everyone in advance for all the help.

---

[Screenshot describing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clhpV.png)

---

My JavaScript code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

const itemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);

const item1 = new Item({
    name: "test"
});
item1.save();

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    console.log("get request received");
    Item.deleteMany({name: "test"});
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Terminal output:

```
$ node app.js
(node:2868) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: useNewUrlParser is a deprecated option: useNewUrlParser has no effect since Node.js Driver version 4.0.0 and will be removed in the next major version       
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Server started on port 3000
get request received
```

Database entries after running the application and sending `GET` request:

```
testDB> db.items.find()
[
  { _id: ObjectId('658de5a4687d08a6d992f578'), name: 'test', __v: 0 },
  { _id: ObjectId('658de5df82d80828a24ef6ca'), name: 'test', __v: 0 },
  { _id: ObjectId('658de60b1fb7cb4857d913d3'), name: 'test', __v: 0 }
]
```

**Tried:** deleteOne() and deleteMany() commands.

**Expected to happen:** deleting all the elements with the name "test" in the database.

**Actually resulted:** objects store in the database but no deleting of the elements happen.

Comment: Please paste your code into the question as formatted code blocks. Do not upload images of code so that someone can help you with a solution.

Comment: @jQueeny Thank you for the tip, I updated the question the code samples.

Comment: The `GET` HTTP method (`app.get` is semantically idempotent (should not have side effects like deleting records from databases) use `POST` for that (`app.post`).  Also, your `app.get` route doesn't issue a response, but you should: e.g. `res.sendStatus(200);` or whatever's appropriate.

Comment: Is the collection name `items` or `Item`? Are you sure you are creating mongoose model with the correct collection name?

Comment: @Wyck I created a HTML page with the submit button to send a `POST` request and moved `Item.deleteMany({name: "test"})` to the `app.post("/")` route but it still doesn't delete elements from the database.

Comment: @ray Collection name in the MongoDB database is `items`, but according to official mongoose documentation you should declare your model as a singular object. MongoDB renames the collection then automatically to a plural form.

Comment: Important to know that [Mongoose promises documentation says queries are not promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53970784/1563833) and you **must** either call .exec, .then or await them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongoose database operations need to be executed using their `then()` function or alternatively using `async/await` which allows them to behave as if they returned a settled promise because [mongoose queries are not actually promisies](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html). They can also be executed using the `exec()` function which *will* return a promise and will behave as such. If you do not use `then()` or `async/await` then the query will not execute.

Two examples would be:

```js
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    console.log("get request received");
    Item.deleteMany({name: "test"}).then(obj => {
       console.log(obj.deletedCount);
       res.send(`Deleted ${obj.deletedCount} documents`);
    }).catch(err => {
       console.log(err);
       res.send(`Error on server`);
    });
});
```

or

```js
app.get("/", async function(req, res){ //< Mark as async
   console.log("get request received");
   try{
      const obj = await Item.deleteMany({name: "test"});
      res.send(`Deleted ${obj.deletedCount} documents`);
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      res.send(`Error on server`);
   }
});
```

These give you the two asynchronous patterns that you can adopt for your database queries to get you started but when deleting records you should pass a resource identifier in your requests such as the `ObjectId` of the document and use approporaite HTTP request verbs eg. [`app.delete`](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.delete.method) and [`app.post`](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.post.method).

Comment: This worked for me, thank you very much! Definitely will look more into it.

Comment: Once you get used to adding and deleting documents look as passing parameters into the route and using them to perform CRUD operations eg. `app.get('/items/:itemid')` means you can access `itemid` in the `req.params.itemid` property and use that to get the item from the database or update it etc.

Comment: But **why** doesn't an unawaited or unchained `Item.deleteMany` actually work in this case? Why does adding `.then(() => {})` make it work?

Comment: @jQueeny It's a legitimate question.  If you call an async function like `async function example() { console.log('running'); return somethingElse(); }` it *will* display "running", but you just can't get the result of `somethingElse` until you await it (or use a .then).  So I'm legitimately curious how awaiting the promise solves the problem.  The op program didn't exit - there's an express server with event listeners. So I was actually expecting the `.deleteMany` to happen and be realized in the database. But it seems it does not unless you either await it or .then something.

Comment: @Wyck it's because mongoose queries aren't actually promises. They have a `then` function and can be used with `async/await` for convenience so the query doesn't actually get executed until you call `then`, or use `exec` (which does return a promise), or use `await`. All OP did was prepare his `deleteMany`. It wasn't executed. I imagine his browser just kept hanging while waiting for a response from that `get` request.

Comment: @jQueeny I think that little nugget about "mongoose queries aren't actually promises" is actually the smoking gun that explains the whole problem and should be added to your answer.

Comment: @Wyck yes I agree that would be useful. I wanted to avoid a rabbit hole of when is an async call not a promise etc when all OP needed to do was execute the queries as if they behaved like a promise. I will add in.